# When UNION stops being superior than OR conditions in SQL queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

In most cases, when I tried to remove OR condition and replace them with a UNION (which holds each of the conditions separately), it performed significantly better, as those parts of the query were index-able again.

Is there a rule of thumb (and maybe some documentation to support it) on when this 'trick' stops being useful? Will it be useful for 2 OR conditions? for 10 OR conditions? As the amount of UNIONs increases, and the UNION distinct part may have its own overhead.

What would be your rule of thumb on this?

Small example of the transformation:

```
SELECT 
    a, b
FROM
    tbl
WHERE
    a = 1 OR b = 2
```

Transformed to:

```
(SELECT 
    tbl.a, tbl.b
FROM
    tbl
WHERE
    tbl.b = 2) 
UNION DISTINCT 
(SELECT 
    tbl.a, tbl.b
FROM
    tbl
WHERE
    tbl.a = 1)
```

Comment: If there was a universal rule for this, do you not think the implementers of the query optimizer would *already perform this mechanical transformation for you*?

Comment: Trust the optimizer, write code easy to understand and maintain!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I know there isn't a universal rule that will always work, but this one tends to work in most cases, so no, I don't think the optimizer team would implement it unless it works 100% of the cases (and I'm not looking for 100%, I'm more after 'most cases', to know what is the best practice when I write queries).

Comment: Best practice is to avoid such tricks. (Unless really, really needed.)

Comment: @jarlh - why? such OR conditions are not indexable. Not trying to bypass that will be just ignoring the reality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest there is no useful Rule of Thumb (RoT).  Here is why...

- As you imply, more `UNIONs` implies slower work, while more `ORs` does not (at least not much).  The `SELECTs` of a union are costly because they are separate.  I would estimate that a `UNION` of N `SELECTs` takes about N+1 or N+2 units of time, where one indexed `SELECT` takes 1 unit of time.  In contrast, multiple `ORs` does little to slow down the query, since fetching all rows of the table is the costly part.
- How fast each `SELECT` of a `UNION` runs depends on how good the index is and how few rows are fetched.  This can vary significantly.  (Hence, it makes it hard to devise a RoT.)
- A `UNION` starts by generating a temp table into which each `SELECT` adds the rows it finds.  This is some overhead.  In newer versions (5.7.3 / MariaDB 10.1), there are limited situations where the temp table can be avoided.  (This eliminates the hypothetical +1 or +2, thereby adding more complexity into devising a RoT.)
- If it is `UNION DISTINCT` (the default) instead of `UNION ALL`, there needs to be a dedup-pass, probably involving a sort over the temp table.  Note: This means that the even the new versions cannot avoid the temp table.  `UNION DISTINCT` precisely mimics the `OR`, yet *you* may know that `ALL` would give the same answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain your thoughts, it was very helpful. So from your perspective, you just always try both methods to see which performs better for that specific query and stick with it?

Comment: Well,, few things to union, and selects are selective --> `UNION`.  In the opposite direction --> `OR`.  Somewhere in the middle --> flip a coin; the difference probably won't matter enough.

Comment: Not sure I understood - what do you mean by "few things to union"?

Comment: @TomShir Turning 2 things in an `OR` into 2 `SELECTs` in a `UNION` is a "few".  10 is not a few.  (Yes, this is vague.  But I claim I can't make a usable RoT.)